# Web scraping account with login info displays inaccurate information

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm using Python's `requests` package to login to [Beatport](https://www.beatport.com/) and I want to scrape the songs in my shopping cart. This is how my cart looks when I login from a browser:
[image: BeatportCart]
As you can see, there's a `div class="cart-tracks"` that contains a list `ul`. The `ul`'s list items each represent a song which are the objects of interest for me here.

Here's my code:

```py
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USERNAME = "<MY USERNAME>"
PASSWORD = "<MY PASSWORD>"

LOGIN_URL = "https://www.beatport.com/account/login"
URL = "https://www.beatport.com/cart"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='_csrf_token']/@value")))[0]

    # Create payload
    payload = {
            "username": USERNAME,
            "password": PASSWORD,
            "_csrf_token": authenticity_token
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers=dict(referer=LOGIN_URL))

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers=dict(referer=URL))
    print(result.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, when I print `result.text`, it looks like my cart is empty:

```html
      <!-- TRACKS BUCKET -->
      <div class="bucket tracks cart-tracks cart-section"></div>
      <!-- End Tracks Bucket -->
```

The login request seems to be successful when I print `result.ok` so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** Here's the XHR request:
[image: XHR]
I believe that `items` is what populates the tracks. I'm pretty new to web scraping, how would I post that request?

Comment: Worth checking is if the card-tracks has data if you look at the *raw* source of the page in your browser (for most browser you can use Ctrl-U to view the source)... it may be that another request is made via ajax and the items are populated from that request

Comment: You're right, it's not in there. So I'm assuming it's being populated by JS then right? In that case, is there any way I can get that data without having to use Selenium?

Comment: Look at your browser developer tools in the network tab... and look for an XHR request that returns the actual data that's used to populate the DOM and then re-create that request using requests

Comment: I just added a picture of the XHR request. If it's not too much to ask, how would I go about posting that request and getting the data?

Comment: Don't have too much time to spend on this but generally you'd make a `.get` request (if that's what's being made - look at the network tab) to that url (along with any params needed - so check out the headers pane) and then you should be able on the response object be able to do `.json()` on it to get the data as a python dictionary... then take the items from that...